# How to print only the second element of the sorted array?

Tags: c, sorting, arraylist

Here i have sorted the array in ascending order.Now i want to only print the second element of the sorted array. Below code prints the second element of the unsorted array. What can I do?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include <math.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>

 int main() {
 int n,b[n],i,j;

scanf("%d",&n);

for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    scanf("%d",&b[i]);
for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++)
{
    for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
    {
        if(b[i]>b[j])
        {
           int a=b[i];
            b[i]=b[j];
            b[j]=a;

        }
    }

}

printf("%d",b[1]);

/* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */    
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Looks like you're already doing that?

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings and read them. They will show you a critical bug.

Comment: `b[n]`, `n` is indeterminate.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `n` when used to specify array dimension?

Comment: n can be any positive value

Comment: Looks alright here -  https://ideone.com/Bx77ya

Comment: If `b[1]` isn't the second element of the sorted array, then `b` isn't a sorted array.

Comment: If i print **b** then i will get the sorted elements. But i am unable to print only the second element @TomKarzes

Comment: But in my compiler i am not getting. is it compiler problem? @pankaj

Comment: No, array that you're declaring is of size n, which you are taking as input later. take the input first, then create array

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
int n,b[n],i,j;
```

When you declare `b[n]`, `n` is indeterminate it can have any junk value thus can result into UB in later stages.

Declare `b` after getting `n` from user.

```
 int n,i,j;

 scanf("%d",&n);

 int b[n]; //or int *b = malloc(sizeof(int)*n); and later do free(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define n as constant or use malloc for array allocation.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#define n 5 
int main() {
 int b[n],i,j;

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     scanf("%d",&b[i]);

 for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++) {
     for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
     {
         if(b[i]>b[j])
         {
            int a=b[i];
             b[i]=b[j];
             b[j]=a;

         }
     }

 }

 printf("%d",b[1]);

 /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
return 0; 
}
```

or

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main() {
 int n,i,j;
 scanf("%d",&n);

 int *b = malloc(sizeof(int)*n);

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
     scanf("%d",&b[i]);

 for(i=0;i<=n-2;i++) {
     for(j=i+1;j<n;j++)
     {
         if(b[i]>b[j])
         {
            int a=b[i];
             b[i]=b[j];
             b[j]=a;

         }
     }

 }

 printf("%d",b[1]);

 free(b);
 /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */ 
return 0; 
}
```